# Distribution of time when two events of type A and two events of type B have happened in Poisson Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

> Consider two Poisson Random Processes $A(t), B(t)$ with parameters $a,
> > b$. Let $T$ be the time where exactly two events of type A and exactly
>   two events of type B have occurred. What distribution does $T$ follow?

My attempt:

Consider $X = X_1 + X_2$ the time that two events of type A have occurred and $Y = Y_1 + Y_2$ the time when two events of type B have occurred. The interarrival times follow exponential distribution so $X \sim G(2, a), Y \sim G(2, b)$
Let $T = \max (X, Y)$

Then $$F_T(t) = \Pr[T \le t] = \Pr [X \le t] \Pr [Y \le t] = F_X(t)F_Y(t) $$
and its PDF is $$f_T(t) = f_X(t) F_Y(t) + f_Y(t) F_X(t)$$

Is my approach right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but to justify it, you need to use that $\{A(t)\ge 2\}=\{X\le t\}$ and $\{B(t)\ge 2\}=\{Y\le t\}$. In particular,
$T=  \min\{t\ge 0: A(t)\ge 2, B(t)\ge 2\} = \min\{t\ge 0: X\le t, Y\le t \}=\max(X,Y) $.
Then if both processes are independent, you can use your argument.

Comment: Thank you very much! Another question: Does this distribution have a name?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think that the distribution of $T$ is "standard"